# Drawing roadmap with more than 8 waypoints using Google directions API Issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw road map with multiple waypoints.As per google API,you can use only 8 waypoint and for business development you can use only 23 waypoints but that is not enough to draw the accurate travel map.

I got one notable solution [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-level?noredirect=1#comment28250800_8779886) but did't works properly.

This solution has one issue for some point it wont't be able to draw the roadmap.

If you open my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67tbw/28/.) the you can see that there are a brach of way points:

like:-

var points = [[28.595161666666666, 77.31429666666666], [28.602561666666663, 77.31256166666667], [28.594639999999995, 77.30559166666667], [28.585825, 77.30017], [28.58475333333333, 77.30100333333333], [28.583985, 77.30347166666667], [28.584005, 77.30288], [28.584428333333335, 77.30269166666668], [28.584080000000004, 77.30304], [28.583235, 77.30358500000001], [28.584435, 77.30268333333333], [28.583306666666665, 77.30265666666666], [28.584278333333334, 77.30283833333333], [28.586365, 77.29805166666667], [28.583978333333334, 77.30177], [28.584324999999996, 77.30284166666667], [28.584238333333328, 77.30340666666666], [28.584101666666665, 77.30290666666666], [28.590111666666665, 77.30175666666668], [28.584323333333334, 77.30297333333333], [28.584215000000004, 77.30304666666666], [28.583788333333338, 77.30260666666666], [28.584193333333328, 77.303015], [28.583798333333334, 77.30157833333332], [28.584288333333333, 77.30296166666668], [28.583810000000003, 77.30295333333333], [28.583908333333337, 77.30201166666667], [28.58464333333333, 77.30217833333333], [28.584111666666665, 77.30134833333334], [28.587213333333338, 77.29757166666667], [28.58387, 77.29434666666666], [28.575966666666666, 77.28125833333334]]

These data set('points') return an error as `status` = `ZERO_RESULTS`

Now If you remove the last point (`[28.575966666666666, 77.28125833333334]`) from the points array then this will work properly and  status will be `OK`.

Why am I getting `ZERO_RESULTS` instead of `OK` ? How can I skip those problematic points ?

### Here is my JSFiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/67tbw/28/

Comment: Check this out [Easy Solution to the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev/39853476#39853476)

Comment: See my answer in similar question with full code example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev/43458012#43458012

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finaly fixed it.Now it will work with any number of point and now `status = ZERO_RESULTS` will not be a problem.

The problem was for some points I was getting `status=ZERO_RESULT`.After that it stopped executing and due to that I was not getting the map.So to fix that problem I came with the solution of skipping the particular point whenever status is not equal to `OK`.Then proceed with the rest of the point. To do that i took two parameter one is for storing the last index and other is path. Because when I will not get OK status then I will not be able to get the lastIndx and path from the status so when ever i am getting the problem then it will go to the else part and there I did like this.

```
1. lastIndx = lastIndx+1 ,
2. gDirRequest(service, waypoints, userFunction,lastIndx , path)
```

*call the function again until the last point.In between if I got status is OK then I will store the path as current path and lastIndx as current index (lastIndx = s[1]).

check this JSFiddle: - http://jsfiddle.net/kousik/2pNKH/

Comment: Hi @Kousik, can you explain in your answer how you fixed it please?

Comment: hey @CrazyTim.The problem was for some perticular point your code was getting status=ZERO_RESULT and after that it stopped executing  and thats why I was not getting the map. so to fix that i am skipping the perticular point whenever i will get status not equal to OK.and proceed with the rest of the point. To do that i took two parameter one is for storing the last index and other is path. coz when i will not get OK status then i will not be able to get the lastIndx and path from the status.. read next comment

Comment: so when ever i am getting the problem then it will go to the else part and there i did like this. 1. lastIndx = lastIndx+1 , 2. gDirRequest(service, waypoints, userFunction,lastIndx , path) *call the function again until the last point.and in between if i got status is OK then i store the path as current path and lastIndx as current index (lastIndx = s[1]). i think you got it.if you have some doubt i will clear. thanks

Comment: be mindful you don't rely on this method too much for error catching as it will increase the number of calls to the API.

Comment: I  know it will increase the call but its fine for me.Have you any other solution? then please provide the jsFiddle.

Comment: Nothing better than what you have done :). Also might be a good idea to provide feedback to the user on how many latlongs have been excluded from the route.