# How to draw polyline using hundreds of waypoints (may be more than 300) swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Basically, I have searched a lot but mostly answer are for javaScrip and I want some code example in swift and according to google we can not use more than 25 way points in a single request

I already have seen, the links blow.
[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038388/google-map-direction-services-waypoints-more-than-50).
[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints)

How to draw polyline using more than hundred waypoints (may be more than 300) swift 5?
I am using GoogleMaps.
My code and api.

```
func getDotsToDrawRoute(positions: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
                if positions.count > 0 {
                    let origin = positions.first
                    let destination = positions.last
                    var wayPoint = ""
                    var wayPoints: [String] = []
                    for point in positions {
                        wayPoint = wayPoint.count == 0 ? "\(point.latitude), \(point.longitude)" : "\(wayPoint)|\(point.latitude), \(point.longitude)"
                        
                        wayPoints.append(wayPoint)
                    }
                    
                    print("exactWayPoint:\(wayPoint)")
                    print("exactWayPoint:\(wayPoints)")
                    
                    let stringURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin!.latitude),\(origin!.longitude)&destination=\(destination!.latitude),\(destination!.longitude)&wayPoints=\(wayPoints)&key=\(Google_API_Key)&sensor=false&mode=walking&waypoints"
                    let url = URL(string: stringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)!
                    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("error in task: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        } else {
                            do {
                                if let dictionary: [String: Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {
                                    print("Dictionary: \(dictionary)")
                                    if let routes = dictionary["routes"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                                        if routes.count > 0 {
                                            let first = routes.first
                                            if let legs = first!["legs"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                                                let fullPath: GMSMutablePath = GMSMutablePath()
                                                for leg in legs {
                                                    if let steps = leg["steps"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                                                        for step in steps {
                                                            if let polyline = step["polyline"] as? [String: Any] {
                                                                if let points = polyline["points"] as? String {
                                                                    fullPath.appendPath(path: GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: points))
                                                                    self.drawRoutes(polyStr: points)
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch let parseError {
                                print("JSON Error: \(parseError.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    task.resume()
                } else {
                    showAlert(title: "OOps!", message: "No data found")
                }
            }
            
            func drawRoutes(polyStr: String) {
                if let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: polyStr) {
                    let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                    polyline.path = path
                    polyline.strokeWidth = 4.0
                    polyline.strokeColor = .blue
                    polyline.geodesic = true
                    self.mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                    polyline.map = self.mapView
                } else {
                    print("path is nill")
                }
            }
    
    // MARK - PATHDelegate
    extension GMSMutablePath {
        func appendPath(path: GMSPath?) {
            if let path = path {
                for i in 0..<path.count() {
                    self.add(path.coordinate(at: i))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The solution is simple and does not depend on the programming language you are using: split the route in segments containing the max allowed amount of waypoints.