# How to optimize a route with Google-API Maps for more than 23 waypoints?

Tags: google-maps, optimization, routes, directions

could someone please point me out the part of the route optimization for routes with more than 23 waypoints?
I want to buy a 'Google-API-Maps for Work License', but it seems that it is not possible to optimize the whole route, when it has more than 23 waypoints.

For instance, if I have a route with 40 waypoints, that needs to go from Point A to point B via 40 waypoints, I need to create the following requests:

Request 1:
Origin: Point A
Waypoints: Waypoint 1 through to waypoints 23
Destination: Waypoint 24

Request 2:
Origin: Waypoint 24
Waypoints: Waypoint 25 through to Waypoint 40
Destination:  Point B

I would get 2 responses, the first the route from Point A to Waypoint 24 and the second the route from waypoint 24 to Point B. After that, I would combine these 2 routes to get one single route.

**But what about the route-optimization?** In this case I would not be able to optimize the **whole** route, starting from the first Point A to the last Point B.

Any solutions for this problem?

Regards
Lenny

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is well answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-level?rq=1). Unfortunately, as mentioned in the response, the work-around would involve a lot more coding but it will solve all your troubles without having to pay anything more than you already have.