# is it possible to draw unlimited waypoints on google maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, memory-management, routes

I have a project and I need to plot more than 10 waypoints on google maps. Is it possible to draw unlimited waypoints on google maps? Thanks for the response. very much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to plot more than 10 (say 11) waypoints?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev

Comment: it says that the request must be limited to 8 waypoints only.

Comment: I have already figured it out thanks to your answers guys :)