# Angular ngMap Google Directions waypoint doesn't recognize array

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use waypoints in array:

```
var way = [{ location: { lat: 51.546550, lng: 0.026345 }, stopover: true }, { location: { lat: 51.5493953, lng: 0.0412878 }, stopover: true }];
```

And load on map like this:

```
        <ng-map center="51.546550, 0.026345" zoom="13">
            <directions draggable="true"
                        panel="directions-panel"
                        waypoints="way"
                        origin="51.546550, 0.026345"
                        destination="51.5493953, 0.0412878">
            </directions>               
        </ng-map>
```

For some reason the error I am getting is:

> InvalidValueError: in property waypoints: not an Array

If I use array directly it works:

```
<ng-map center="51.546550, 0.026345" zoom="13">
            <directions draggable="true"
                        panel="directions-panel"
                        waypoints="[{ location: { lat: 51.546550, lng: 0.026345 }, stopover: true }, { location: { lat: 51.5493953, lng: 0.0412878 }, stopover: true }]"
                        origin="51.546550, 0.026345"
                        destination="51.5493953, 0.0412878">
            </directions>               
        </ng-map>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you do have a controller right for the view?? mind to share it? cause i think that your var way in not being binded to the waypoints and its taking it as a string and not the json object you have defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You can use either `waypoints="{{ways}}"` or `ng-waypoints = "ways"`. In the below markup I used `ng-waypoints`. Example [here](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!directions.html)

```
<ng-map zoom="13" center="51.546550, 0.026345" >
   <directions draggable="true"
                    panel="directions-panel"
                    ng-waypoints='ways'
                    origin="51.546550, 0.026345"
                    destination="51.5493953, 0.0412878">
        </directions>               
  </ng-map>
```

The js files I used are

```
<script src="ng-map.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

**Below doesnt work**

Can you try `$scope.way` instead of `var way`

Comment: actually at the moment i just created array in html directly with JS, but i have one in angularJs controller scope and it's the same thing. for some reason waypoints doesn't work with objected array.

Comment: @NagaSandeep, By Default google allowed 23 waypoints, How to polt more than 23 waypoints?

Comment: @Irfan, a simple google search redirected me to this stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev

Comment: @NagaSandeep, I did it in Js, but make problem in angularjs