# How can use more of 23 waypoints with a single request in google directions API (premium account)?

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

is there a legal/straight possibility to use more of 23 waypoints in a single request to google maps api directions?
We have to change our plan? How and what?
We've a premium account and we need to use directions to make a call with more of 23 waypoints.
No workaround please.

Thank you

Comment: If you are not looking for a workaround then it sounds like to me you're suggesting a feature change of Google Maps; and for that you shouldn't be placing it on Stack Overflow. Use Google Maps support and get in touch with them directly.

Comment: No Luke, I'm asking here to understand if there's something that i don't know or if i making mistake with the api of google maps directions. Thank you anyway

Comment: And anyway, the google official support for maps api indicate this place to make question about the code or api. It seems to be ridicolous but it's so.
It seems to not exist a real time support or a official forum in their websites.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, if you are not looking for a workaround then it sounds like to me you're suggesting a feature change of Google Maps. But after you replied I can see you just want to confirm if this is the case with Google Maps API service.

Well as you can see on the [GMaps bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6838), there is already an ongoing discussion to have the restriction raised or removed. The free version limits you to 10 waypoints per request and the paid version (your version) give you the full access to 24 waypoints. After looking around, it still appears the 'paying them money to remove restriction' approach is not going to work with Google as shown on their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits) and in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev?rq=1). That waypoint limitation is put in place to prevent downloading whole GMaps database via repetitive routing.

The only approach is to use a work around or another service. I suggest if you have 40 waypoints for example, that you stitch together two routes using the same color and make them appear to be one route.

I know it's not the answer you want, but it's likely that Google can't handle the large requests that you're imposing so they are purposely bottle necking their waypoint limit to give everyone a fair service. You can of course contact their sale department and see if they will offer you a specific limit, but that will come with a big invoice as well :)

Good luck on finding your solution and let me know how it goes, very interested to see if Google changes this limit or give an official work around.

Comment: Thank you very much Luke.
After our last discussion and after i've checked that there's not solution, I wrote to google to ask an improvement.
I'm still waiting a response,
Thank you again :)

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroM. - could you accept this as the answer (the checkmark on the left hand side of the question) if this has answered your question. Let's see if google actually replies to you haha