# How to calculate distance using lists of coordinates with Google Maps Roads API

Tags: ruby, google-maps, google-roads-api

I'm generating static map with **snapToRoads** (since it accepts multiple waypoints).

Given I have lists of coordinates, how can I calculate distance between  those coordinates and sum it to get **total driving distance**.

Or is there other better way to do it in **ruby code** ?

Sample snap-to-roads request:

```
waypoints = [arrays of coordinates]
snap_to_roads_url = "https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=#{waypoints.join('|')}&interpolate=true&key=API_KEY"
snappedPoints = HTTParty.get(URI.encode(snap_to_roads_url))

# Store snapped polyline returned by the snap-to-road service
snappedPoints['snappedPoints'].each do |snap|
  snappedCoordinates << "#{snap['location']['latitude']},#{snap['location']['longitude']}"
  placeIdArray << snap['placeId']
end
```

Static Map request:

```
https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=650x550&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=size:small&maptype=roadmap&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:red%7C54.57424022982199,-1.2351261042386523|54.57423420000001,-1.2351275000000002|54.57423420000001,-1.2351275000000002 ...many more
```

And also any idea how can I include **markers** with the above request, given I have **origin and destination coordinates**.

Please help!

Comment: why don't you read about haversine formula. here it is a link  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula.   I think it can help, there are several examples of obtaining the distance between two coordinates.  here you are a good example  https://github.com/kristianmandrup/haversine

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your snapToRoads request (redact your API KEY)?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: You added your static map call, not the snapToRoads request.  What issue are you having calculating the distance between them and summing it to get the total distance?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, for your use-case, that you instead use the Directions API Web Service. You can also put multiple waypoints (up to 23 per request) and its return will generate an encoded polyline of your path. It will also provide travel distance, travel time, etc.

Learn more about it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

Snap To Roads need your coordinates to be very near each other to work properly and your static map url might get too lengthy after a few points. Some browsers may reach its url limit, and Static Maps has an [8192 character limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#url-size-restriction)

Here's a sample request with the Directions Web Service (just include your own API key):
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-37.59431782470163%2C144.91110764394534&destination=place_id%3AEipTeWRuZXkgUm9hZCwgU29tZXJ0b24sIFZpY3RvcmlhLCBBdXN0cmFsaWE&mode=driving&waypoints=place_id%3AEjJNaXRmb3JkIENyZXNjZW50LCBDcmFpZ2llYnVybiwgVmljdG9yaWEsIEF1c3RyYWxpYQ%7Cplace_id%3AEi5FZGluZ3RvbiBXYXksIENyYWlnaWVidXJuLCBWaWN0b3JpYSwgQXVzdHJhbGlh&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

For a more visual representation you go to this (Include your API key to see JSON results)[link](https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/?origin=-37.59431782470163%2C144.91110764394534&destination=place_id%3AEipTeWRuZXkgUm9hZCwgU29tZXJ0b24sIFZpY3RvcmlhLCBBdXN0cmFsaWE&mode=driving&waypoints=place_id%3AEjJNaXRmb3JkIENyZXNjZW50LCBDcmFpZ2llYnVybiwgVmljdG9yaWEsIEF1c3RyYWxpYQ%7Cplace_id%3AEi5FZGluZ3RvbiBXYXksIENyYWlnaWVidXJuLCBWaWN0b3JpYSwgQXVzdHJhbGlh)

Then in its result, you can get an encoded polyline at its property: `routes.overview_polyline`. You can use that as your encoded polyline path like so: `&path=geodesic:true%7Ccolor:0x0057E7ff%7Cenc:ENCODED_POLYLINE_HERE`

Your markers' coordinates can be retrieved by getting each leg of the route. Start with `routes[0].legs[0].start_location` and `end_location` Use those coordinates for your markers.

For your total driving distance, every `leg` has a `distance` property with numerical values. Just add all the `legs` for your total distance and even time.

Your static map request will be similar to the attached code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=800x800
            &maptype=roadmap
  &key=AIzaSyCD0rWgXRVBa7PgaTWXVp_gU51pgHGviYY&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:A%7C-37.5943328,144.9110993&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:B%7C-37.60746779999999,144.9393146&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:C%7C-37.6118511,144.9329711&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:D%7C-37.6302591,144.9490315&path=geodesic:true%7Ccolor:0x0057E7ff%7Cenc:psmdFk}msZeApE~APxAJvK~@pCLdA@dD?fACbESlEYbAIlB[`Dg@bBYtJeCbEcAfDo@q@_D]cBM_AEg@Eu@@sAJyAVuArAoFRqAJ_A?o@CACECG@OFKBABCJu@NyBEeAq@kEaAsGI}@EwA^uG@[AACGAEBMBC@A?{@@M?o@QuAa@sAq@yASu@Ko@I}A?u@V}DLyBAQA[?SAAAG?OFKLAHFbAL|JdALBRHZ@P?H@@ABEBAFg@FKj@gJT}CTqAZeAVs@bC}EVk@Lc@NaAFaAAy@IkAUq@A?EAGK?O?AOg@U_@o@q@g@[e@Q[Ie@G_CS_ACgAH_D^KFSF?@A@A@C@EA?AYAGC[?u@Es@Ok@Sm@_@k@e@eBmBUY`CkClE}Eh@[\Gd@Ce@B]FWLQLmE|EaCjCTXdBlBj@d@l@^j@Rr@Nt@DZ?FEJAJA@A?ABAF@RAL@dEe@bAAfAFfBN^Hb@Lf@Vf@`@n@v@`@^F@BBDLALDb@AXHjA@x@G`AGh@VHl@Z`@\x@fAy@gAa@]m@[WIFi@FaAAy@IkAUq@A?EAGK?O?AOg@U_@o@q@g@[e@Q[Ie@G_CS_ACgAH_D^KFSF?@A@A@G@AA?AYAGC[?u@Es@Ok@Sm@_@k@e@eBmBe@q@a@s@w@gBg@cBEEKe@A?CC?A?I?AG{@KcAGoACwBGk@Ok@Qi@Ye@YWSSUKA@CAGE?Ec@I_@Ka@QmKkD_@Ec@Mc@]ICCCQGe@EKAiAHUDa@NOLGRU`BKb@Gf@?h@DH@LELGFIBKAIGAA?Ai@GOKi@O}@Y_@E]Mo@c@e@s@Se@Mi@E[?S?GRCzBW~A]vBu@tFqCtCyAzAi@lA[rC]hCOnIa@`[uApQ}AvL_A~D]nBMhBQdBKdSkBnUsBfb@aDzD]Bv@q@H"/> 


</body>
</html>
```

If you want things to be interactive though (similar to the Directions webapp I linked) then you'll need to use the [Google Maps Javascript API Directions Service] (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions).

Hope these help!

Here's some more about encoded polylines and markers with static map:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Paths

Comment: Hi henrisycip, my waypoints is over 50, I tried Directions API Web Service and got error exceeding limit of 8 waypoints per request, that's why I moved to snap-to-roads

Comment: You have a limit of 23 waypoints including your origin and destination now in the Free tier. And you can simply connect together 2-3 Directions Web Service requests to create an output for 50 waypoints. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev?rq=1)