# Google direction async call and waypoint limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I need to create a webapp in php where I set a start point, an end point and some waypoint between the route. I don't need optimization of the route: I need to pass through cities using the order passed in the array.

I know the limitation of 23 waypoints for a call so I found this interesting workaround to get it working: [Exceed 23 waypoint per request limit on Google Directions API (Business/Work level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev)

Now I edited the code based on my needs like this:

(I set 8 instead 23 waypoint for semplicity here.)

css part:

```css
.pin-waypoint {

  background-color: #4285F4;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.pin-waypoint::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid #4285F4;
}
```

html part:

```html
...
<div id="map" style="height: 800px"></div>
<div id="directions-panel" style="height: 800px"></div>
...
```

ajax.php:

```php
if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "getRouteSteps" ) {
   
  $start = "Miami";
  $waypoints_ordered = ["Dallas", "Houston", "Atlanta", "Nashville", "Whashington", "Cincinnati", "Indianapolis", "Kansas City", "Denver", "Las Vegas", "Phoenix", "Tucson", "Albuquerque", "Santa Fe", "Oklahoma City"];

  $array_steps = [];
  foreach ( $waypoints_ordered as $i => $k ) {
    $array_steps[] = [
        "City" => $k,
        "Order" => $i+1
    ];
}
$end = "Memphis";
array_unshift($array_steps, ["City" => $start , "Order" => 0]);
$array_steps[] = ["City" => $end , "Order" => count($waypoints_ordered)+1 ];

$result = [
    "Waypoints" => $array_steps
];

echo json_encode($result);

exit();

}
```

jquery:

```js
async function aggiorna_mappa() {

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

  const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 15,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
});

var steps = [];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    dataType:"json",
    url: "ajax/ajax.php",
    data: { 'action': 'getRouteSteps' },
    success: function(response, status) {
        
        steps = response.Waypoints;
        
    }
});

// Divide route to several parts because max stations limit is X+2 (X waypoints + 1 origin + 1 destination)
// I've set 8 instead 23
for (var i = 0, parts = [], max = 8 - 1; i < steps.length; i = i + max)
    parts.push(steps.slice(i, i + max + 1));

// Send requests to service to get route (for stations count <= X+2 only one request will be sent)
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

    var waypoints = [];
    for (var j = 1; j < parts[i].length - 1; j++)
        waypoints.push({location: parts[i][j]['City'], stopover: true});
    
    var ordinamento_start = parts[i][0]['Order'];
    var ordinamento_end = parts[i][parts[i].length - 1]['Order'];
    
    var service_options = {
        origin: parts[i][0]['City'],
        destination: parts[i][parts[i].length - 1]['City'],
        waypoints: waypoints,
        optimizeWaypoints: false, //<-- I don't have to optimize!
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };
    // Send request
    directionsService.route(service_options, function(response, status) {
        if (status != 'OK') {
            console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            return;
        }
        
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
        
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {   // For each route, display summary information.
            var routeSegment = i + 1;
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Tappa: ' + ordinamento_start +
                '</b><br>';
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' ';
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';

            const pinBackground = new PinElement({
                background: "#FBBC04",
            });
            
            const priceTag = document.createElement("div");

            priceTag.className = "pin-waypoint";
            priceTag.textContent = ordinamento_start;

            
                const AdvancedMarkerElement = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
                  map,
                  position: route.legs[i].steps[0].end_location,
                  title: route.legs[i].start_address,
                  content: priceTag
                });
            
            ordinamento_start++;
            
        }
        
        var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        renderer.setMap(map);
        renderer.setOptions({ suppressMarkers: true, preserveViewport: false });
        renderer.setDirections(response);
    });
}

}
```

Now the problem is the ASYNC calls and "pins" on the maps - and steps on the side of page:

If I try load the page, I get this result for example, where ORDER starts from 14 (why?) with city INDIANAPOLIS:

[image]

If I try to reload the page I can get different "start" point like this:

Pin starts always at 14 (??) but the city associated is "SANTA FE" this time.

[image]

The final route is always the same but I think, cause async calls, sometimetimes a call is retrieved before another and start point is different!

I'd like my start point will be ALWAYS "MIAMI" and the number step start from 1 (not 14).

I don't think google api has a SYNC version of those calls. How can I solve this?

Comment: Whether the requests are made asynchronously is a choice you make in your code, Google doesn't control that

Comment: @ADyson AdvancedMarkerElement works only with async. I need AdvancedMarkerElement cause i need to "write order number" instead the traditional "pin image". Any suggest?

Comment: Also, I tried to remove "async" in my functions (and pins) but calls stay async... I get different result start city on each load page

Comment: `AdvancedMarkerElement works only with async`...still not clear what you mean here, precisely. All you're doing with that variable is making a new class. What's asynchronous  about it, specifically?

Comment: A big logical flaw in your code is `$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    dataType:"json",
    url: "ajax/ajax.php",
    data: { 'action': 'getRouteSteps' },
    success: function(response, status) {
        
        steps = response.Waypoints;
        
    }
});

// Divide route to several parts because max stations limit is X+2 (X waypoints + 1 origin + 1 destination)
// I've set 8 instead 23
for (var i = 0, parts = [], max = 8 - 1; i < steps.length; i = i + max)
    parts.push(steps.slice(i, i + max + 1));
` - `steps` won't be defined until the ajax "success"...

Comment: ...runs, which happens asynchronously, but right on the line below you then start to loop over data and use `steps` in it. It won't be populated yet when that code runs. Maybe that has something to do with your problem. Instead you should likely put anything that relies on `steps` into a function, and then call that function from the "success" callback of the $.ajax call, so that it doesn't run until the ajax request is completed `steps` is correctly populated.

Comment: This is almost certainly going to end up as a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)