# Google Maps, draw lines between more than 8 waypoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

We have json. In json have 10 latitude and 10 longitude.We tried draw line between those points.But We got Status code `google.maps.DirectionsResult.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED`.So after deleted two points.Now We tried to draw the lines between 8 points it's working nice. But in json some time come 50 to 100 latitude and longitude.We tried like this

```
 var aa=waypts[0].location.k;
  var bb=waypts[0].location.D;

  var cc=waypts[waypts.length-1].location.k
  var dd=waypts[waypts.length-1].location.D;

var start1= new google.maps.LatLng(aa,bb);
var end1=new google.maps.LatLng(cc, dd);

  var request = {
      origin: start1,
      destination: end1,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  debugger;

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  debugger;
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
    }
  });
```

first tell me how to draw line between more then 8 points.Please guide me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API \[Directions API\] Waypoints limitation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418875/google-maps-api-directions-api-waypoints-limitation)

Comment: possible related question [Google Maps API to get bus route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315347/google-maps-api-to-get-bus-route)

Comment: possible related question [JavaScript Google Maps polylines : issue in connecting all given GPS locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609872/javascript-google-maps-polylines-issue-in-connecting-all-given-gps-locations)

Comment: See my answer in similar question with full code example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779886/exceed-23-waypoint-per-request-limit-on-google-directions-api-business-work-lev/43458012#43458012

Answer (score 5):

Short answer not in a single request.

The documentation for [Google Maps Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) states that

> `MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED` indicates that too many waypoints were
>   provided in the request The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the
>   origin, and destination. ( [Google Maps API for Work](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/) customers may
>   contain requests with up to 23 waypoints.)

Under the header of Usage Limits

> Users of the free API get Up to 8 waypoints (plus origin and
>   destination) allowed in each request and a total of 2,500 directions
>   requests per 24 hour period.

So if you run multiple requests, fetching 8 waypoints (plus origin and destination) at a time you can achieve this.  Just note the maximum of 2,500 directions requests per 24 hours.

Comment: he just needs to send multiple requests

Comment: What do you mean? I remove downvote when the answer is edited :)

Comment: @A1rPun thanks for reply.Please tell me. if I have 24 latitude and longitude in my json .how to send multiple requests.

Comment: @PavanAlapati I think you need to create another StackOverflow question for that. Sphvn answered this question btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use multiple requests as the other answer suggests. Here is an example:

```
var service = new maps.DirectionsService();
function calcRoute(points, startIndex) {

    var start = points[startIndex];
    var destinationIndex = startIndex + 8 > points.length - 1 ? points.length - 1 : startIndex + 8;
    var destination = points[destinationIndex];

    function handlerRouteResult(result, status) {

        var path = [];
        if (status === maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                calcRoute(points, startIndex);
            }, 100);
        }
        else if (status === maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var overviewPath = result.routes[0].overview_path;
            for (var routePointIndex = 0; routePointIndex < overviewPath.length; routePointIndex++) {
                path.push(overviewPath[routePointIndex]);
            }
        } else {
            for (var pointIndex = startIndex; pointIndex <= destinationIndex; pointIndex++) {
                path.push(points[pointIndex]);
            }
        }

        var line = new maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            strokeColor: '#235c23',
            path: path
        });
    }

    var waypoints = [];
    for (var waypointIndex = startIndex; waypointIndex < destinationIndex - 1; waypointIndex++) {
        waypoints.push({ location: points[waypointIndex] });
    }

    service.route({
        origin: start,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        waypoints: waypoints
    }, handlerRouteResult);
}

for (var i = 0; i < pathPoints.length - 1; i += 8) {
    calcRoute(pathPoints, i);
}
```

It also take the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response in account that you receive you make to many API calls. In this case it will retry the route query.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, it's imposable to do it using Google's JavaScript API. However, Google does allow up to 23 waypoints with a server-side request. So using PHP and JavaScript, I was able to make a workaround.

I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866386/3994029) along with the code.

What you have to do is get the "waypoint order" from the server side request and then have JavaScript give you directions between each location.